# Firebase function deploy error - Failed to parse build specification

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm encountering an issue while trying to deploy my Python-written Firebase function. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

> Error: Failed to parse build specification:
>
> - FirebaseError It seems you are using a newer SDK than this version of the CLI can handle. Please update your CLI with `npm install -g firebase-tools`

Here are the details:

Environment:

firebase-admin: 6.4.0 (latest version) same as Firebase Python SDK
firebase-tools: 13.4.0 (latest version) same as Firebase CLI
Platform: macOS
Python: 3.12

Command Used:

`firebase deploy --debug --only functions`

```
[2024-02-29T15:30:14.892Z] > command requires scopes: 

......

=== Deploying to 'miniproject1-412516'...

......

[2024-02-29T15:30:21.160Z] Customer code is not Node
[2024-02-29T15:30:21.162Z] Validating python source
[2024-02-29T15:30:21.162Z] Building python source
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy 
[2024-02-29T15:30:21.180Z] Found functions.yaml. Got spec: specVersion: 1
version: 1

functions:
  collect_and_save_data_to_firebase_storage:
    name: collect_and_save_data_to_firebase_storage
    runtime: python312
    trigger: http


source: main.py

Error: Failed to parse build specification:
- FirebaseError It seems you are using a newer SDK than this version of the CLI can handle. Please update your CLI with `npm install -g firebase-tools`
```

I've already tried updating the Firebase CLI with npm install -g firebase-tools, but the same error persists. How can I resolve this issue? Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

main.py code added!

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import os
import concurrent.futures
import time
import firebase_admin
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from firebase_admin import credentials, storage, initialize_app
from google.cloud import storage as gcs
import sys
import io

def collect_and_save_data_to_firebase_storage():
    service_account_key = {
     "removed"
    }


    cred = credentials.Certificate(service_account_key)
    initialize_app(cred)

    bucket = storage.bucket()

    def fetch_data_from_api(auth_key, base_url, lastModTsBgn, lastModTsEnd, result_type, page_index, page_size):
        try:
            url = f"{base_url}?authKey={auth_key}&pageIndex={page_index}&pageSize={page_size}&lastModTsBgn={lastModTsBgn}&lastModTsEnd={lastModTsEnd}&resultType={result_type}"
            response = requests.get(url)
            if response.status_code != 200:
                print(f"Failed to fetch data from API (Status code: {response.status_code})", file=sys.stderr)
                return None
            return json.loads(response.text)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while fetching data from API: {str(e)}", file=sys.stderr)
            return None

    def save_data_to_storage(dataframe, storage_path):
        try:
            
            csv_buffer = io.StringIO()
            dataframe.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False)

            # change to binary 
            csv_bytes = csv_buffer.getvalue().encode('utf-8-sig')

            # upload at Firebase Storage
            blob = bucket.blob(storage_path)
            blob.upload_from_string(csv_bytes, content_type='text/csv')
            print(f"CSV file saved to Firebase Storage: {storage_path}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while saving data to Firebase Storage: {str(e)}", file=sys.stderr)

    def process_page(page_data):
        try:
            filtered_data = []
            body = page_data['result']['body']['rows'][0]['row']
            for data in body:
                if data.get('opnSfTeamCode') == 3740000 and (data.get('trdStateNm') == '휴업' or data.get('trdStateNm') == '폐업'):
                    filtered_data.append(data)
            return filtered_data
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while processing the page: {str(e)}", file = sys.stderr)

    def collect_data(auth_key, base_url, lastModTsBgn, lastModTsEnd, result_type, page_size, num_pages_to_fetch):
        filtered_dataset = []
        try:
            for page_index in range(1, num_pages_to_fetch + 1):
                response_data = fetch_data_from_api(auth_key, base_url, lastModTsBgn, lastModTsEnd, result_type, page_index, page_size)
                if response_data is not None:
                    filtered_dataset.extend(process_page(response_data))
            return filtered_dataset
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while collecting the data: {str(e)}", file=sys.stderr)

    def get_total_pages(auth_key, base_url, lastModTsBgn, lastModTsEnd, result_type, page_size):
        try:
            url = f"{base_url}?authKey={auth_key}&pageIndex=1&pageSize={page_size}&lastModTsBgn={lastModTsBgn}&lastModTsEnd={lastModTsEnd}&resultType={result_type}"
            response = requests.get(url)
            if response.status_code != 200:
                print(f"Failed to fetch data from API (Status code: {response.status_code})")
                return 0  # or any other appropriate value
            data = json.loads(response.text)
            total_count = data['result']['header']['paging']['totalCount']
            total_pages = total_count // page_size

            if total_count % page_size > 0:
                total_pages += 1

            return total_pages
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while gettering the total page number: {str(e)}", file = sys.stderr)

    # period
    latestday = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=0)
    maximum_days_ago = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7)
    latestday_str = latestday.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    maximum_days_ago_str = maximum_days_ago.strftime('%Y%m%d')

    # collect data
    auth_key = "removed"
    base_url = "http://www.localdata.go.kr/platform/rest/TO0/openDataApi"
    lastModTsBgn = maximum_days_ago_str  
    lastModTsEnd = latestday_str
    page_size = 500
    result_type = "json"
    storage_path = "newData/extracted_values.csv"
    num_pages_to_fetch = get_total_pages(auth_key, base_url, lastModTsBgn, lastModTsEnd, result_type, page_size)
    refiltered_dataset = collect_data(auth_key, base_url, lastModTsBgn, lastModTsEnd, result_type, page_size, num_pages_to_fetch)

    # to dataframe
    keys_to_extract = ['영업상태명', '폐업일자', '사업장명', '좌표정보(x)', '좌표정보(y)', '도로명전체주소']
    extracted_values = {key: [] for key in keys_to_extract}
    for data in refiltered_dataset:
        for key in keys_to_extract:
            extracted_values[key].append(data.get(key))
    extracted_df = pd.DataFrame(extracted_values)

    new_columns = ['영업상태명', '폐업일자', '사업장명', '좌표정보(x)', '좌표정보(y)', '도로명전체주소']
    extracted_df.columns = new_columns

    # delete NA
    for column in extracted_df.columns:
        extracted_df = extracted_df[extracted_df[column] != '']

    # Reset the index
    extracted_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    # Save CSV file at Firebase Storage
    save_data_to_storage(extracted_df, storage_path)
    print("CSV file saved to Firebase Storage:", storage_path)

# run
collect_and_save_data_to_firebase_storage()
```

firebase.json

```
    {
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "venv",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and i created functions.yaml file because it cause error.

functions.yaml

```
specVersion: 1
version: 1

functions:
  collect_and_save_data_to_firebase_storage:
    name: collect_and_save_data_to_firebase_storage
    runtime: python312
    trigger: pubsub


source: main.py
```

requirements.txt

```
firebase-functions~=0.1.0
requests~=2.31.0
pandas~=2.2.1
firebase-admin~=6.4.0
google-cloud-storage~=2.14.0
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show all of the relevant project you're trying to deploy.  We should be able to copy what you have and run it for ourselves to see the same result.  Also include the version of the CLI you're using with `firebase --version` as well as the versions of all the SDKs you're using.

Comment: Do you have a requirements.txt?  Please provide everything required to compile and deploy.

Comment: yes, sorry again.. it's my first project with firebase :(